# (gitflow) My feature branch contains previous commit not yet merged on other branches

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-flow

I'm working in a `master` `develop` `fb` branch way on git.

I create a `fb` feature branch from `develop`

Once my work is done, I push `fb` to `origin/fb` and do a pull request (with azuredevops) on `fb` to `develop` then `fb` to `master`

In the pull request to `master` I can see previous commits before the branch creation which are other merges on `develop`

```
Develop
---P0---P1---P2-------------------
             |               FB
             \----M1----M2--------

Master
---P0-----------------------------
```

I don't want `P1` and `P2` to be merged on master because other developers are waiting for tests before merging on`master`

What are my options?

- Create a branch from `P0` (and cherry-pick my `fb`commits to fix my case), only `P1` and `P2` want to be merged too, but in the future if there are other previous non commited commits?
- I saw a previous thread where you create a branch from `master`, cherry-pick `fb`'s commits into it and merge this branch to master... Seems complex.
- Is there a way to merge only `fb`'s commits or is it anti-pattern?

What is the correct gitflow for this? In general when do we create a feature branch?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, we could create branch `fb` from `P0` and create branch `fa` from `P2`, then work on the branch `fb`.

Once my work is done, we push `fb` to `origin/fb` and do a pull request (with azuredevops) on `fb` to develop then `fb` to `master`, it will not merge `P1` and `P2` to the branch master.

And if we need the commit `P1` and `P2`, we could push the branch `fa` to `origin/fa` and do a pull request to merge the commit `P1` and `P2`

Comment: This fixes my initial problem, but I'm asking for a more general solution to not have this problem in the future.

Comment: Another way is cherry-pick fb's commits into it and merge this branch to master, apart from these, I am afraid there is no better way